# Intellij and Apache Tomcat not updating

Tags: intellij-idea, war, tomcat8, intellij-14

I have a project going on for a couple of months now using a Spring MVC framework. For developing I am using an Apache Tomcat 8.0.17 with an exploded war file. Everything worked well since yesterday. Now when I change my Java Files the changes are no longer visible. I can even throw runtime exceptions and stuff like that (I always restart the tomcat server). The only way to "update" my code is to rebuild the whole project (Build --> Rebuild Project) which is quite time consuming and very annoying.

I did not change anything in the configuration nor updated Intellij IDEA or the Tomcat Server.

Comment: So...you had your running servlet update with the code changes that you were writing in IntelliJ?  You sure you didn't update IntelliJ?  Were you using a third party plugin to accomplish this (like JRebel)?  If I recall correctly, I don't believe that IntelliJ alone can accomplish this as reliably as JRebel; this coming from a guy that used to work in a Tomcat shop using JRebel.

Comment: Well if I changed anything in my code I just restarted the server. Usually the code was updated then and it took not too long to restart the tomcat server. However, now it doesn't even update the code anymore without rebuilding the whole project first.

Comment: Ohh and no I don't think it's an extra plugin. It's just the start up configuration with a local tomcat server.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. It was working well for months and since yesterday, re-starting Tomcat does not take into account changes made in Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix this by manually deleting all the files in the following folder:

```
%userdir%/.IntelliJIdea14/system/tomcat
```

After a full rebuild the updateing process works perfectly again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this is VM Options:

```
-Dcatalina.home=%tomcat_folder% -Dwtp.deploy=%tomcat_folder%/webapps -Dcatalina.base=%tomcat_folder%
```